# size and position of childViewController within a container view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

First time using container view controllers. I'd like to create the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    FirstViewController *vc=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.fVC=vc;

    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 100.0f);  // <- how do I assign this frame to either my View Controller or the space to which that view will be assigned? 
    self.fVC.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    [self addChildViewController:self.fVC];

    [self.view addSubview:self.fVC.view];
    [self.fVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Currently, this makes the child view take up the whole screen. I'd like to assign the fVC to myFrame. How would I do this?

**** updated #1**

setting the childVC to something like the above to :

```
self.fVC.view.frame=myFrame;
```

sets it to the space but it doesn't really respect the end of text etc...? How should I handle this?

thx in advance

**update2**

Sorry for big pics, just to show everything that is going on. I think it might be something related to clip view as mentioned in the comments.

with
    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f, 300.0f);

[image]

and with:
    CGRect myFrame=CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f, 100.0f);

[image]

Comment: What does "sets it to the space but it doesn't really respect the end of text etc" mean? What text are you talking about. The way you're setting fVC.view's frame is correct.

Comment: It could be you need to set 'clip subviews' property so views won't draw outside of their frame.  You are attempting to build a container view right?  If not, you'd just add UIViews and not UIViewControllers.

Comment: yes, trying to create a container view. First time, though...

Comment: Where is that "first" coming from -- how is it added to fVC's view?

Comment: I put that in the nib file just as a text label. In the second situation, I'm not sure why it isn't 100 pixels vertically?

Comment: Sure you didn't write 10?

Comment: Why not creating a class that overrides the drawRect method and then calling it from your container class

Comment: @DannyLin this will be more functional that what is is now so need to get the container piece working correctly

Comment: @timpone regarding the 100pixels issue, did you turn your autolayout on?

Comment: thx Danny, needed to set layout values. answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you still have a question. To get around the problem of your label being out of the view, it's best to use a freeform controller in your xib, and size it to the size you're going to use when you add it to the other controller's view. This way you can lay things out visually.

Comment: sorry, I know the above is a bit of a mess. I was trying to make it as a simple container controller. What do you mean by freeform exactly?

Comment: @timpone, in IB under Simulated Metrics, freeform is one of the choices in the Size pulldown. Once you change to freeform, you can set the size in the size inspector.

Comment: @timpone, if you set the size in IB, you don't even have to set it in your code. You could just use the center property to place it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

basically, I needed to set my Layout values so:

```
self.fVC.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

live and learn